# Better to SELECT...IN ($csv) or loop through an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

Which of these equivalents is preferable:

```
$medium_csv = implode(",",$medium_array);
mysql_query('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE user_id IN ($medium_csv)');
```

or this:

```
foreach ($medium_array as $array_item) {
    mysql_query('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE user_id = $array_item');
}
```

**The array is between 10 and 500 items if that matters*

Comment: I think the first one is better because the second one will send query request more than one to the database, that will take more time logically.

Comment: My guess: Multiple queries will be slower than one query with an `IN` because mysql will only have to parse one query with `IN` versus 10 to 500 queries.

Comment: This would be a nice time to do some benchmarking. We can't test for your setup. Check out [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) for basic benchmarking in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making between 10 and 500 calls to MySQL is unnecessary, when you have the option to settle with one call. It's as simple as that.

Comment: +1 for you and @DorShermer, I almost needed `microtime()` to see who answered first. :) Guess this was obvious. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Better to `SELECT IN`, especially if user_id is indexed. There really is no reason to run back and forth from php to mysql up to 500 times when one simple SQL statement can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

generaly you should stick with less selects(unless you need select some nasty joins). if you have 2 alternatives, you should always benchmark it. if array is too long maybe it would be good idea to divide it into several pieces but definitely dont select it one by one in loop.